# meaning of ''took to'' and ''up far above''

Tags: meaning-in-context

This sentence is from *Withering Heights*.

> Mr.Earnshaw took to Heathcliff strangely, petting him up far above Cathy.

I want to know the meaning of "took to" and "up far above" in above  sentence.

Answer (score 1):

When you 'take to' something or someone, you become attached to them. If you put something 'up far above' something else, you hold the first thing in higher regard than the second. So it's saying that Mr. Earnshaw began to like Heathcliff more than Cathy.